# CIFS/SMB Network protocol in Android Studio formatting issue

Tags: android, smb

I have jcifs-1.3.19 jar installed with in the android studio project.

I was wondering why I keep getting an exception for "W/System.err: jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

I have successfully accessed my companies Windows network drives using "ES File Explore". I have the correct credentials (login & pswd). The company  "IT" help-desk said the SMB path format is as such:

"static final String AUTH_PATH = “smb://” + USER_NAME + “:” + PASSWORD “@engstl1.us.crownlift.net/vol1/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Exectuion/”;"

This does not work. Is there something I am doing wrong? This code is executing in an AsyncTask.

```
static final String AUTH_PATH = "smb://" + USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@engstl1.us.crownlift.net/vol1/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Exectuion/";  // From email
String Path = AUTH_PATH + "testfile.text"; // From email
static final String fileContent = "Here is something in this file";
static boolean successful;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.i(TAG, "in AsyncTask onPreExecute");   // debug msg
}
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try{
        Log.i(TAG, "IN AsyncTask in try ---------------------------->:" );   // debug msg
        String user = USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
        System.out.println("User: " + user);

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
        //String path = NETWORK_FOLDER + "testfile.txt";
        String path = Path;  // From email
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        Log.i(TAG, "IN doInBackground method in try after NtlmPasswordAuthentication ---------------------------->:" + auth);   // debug msg

        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        Log.i(TAG, "IN doInBackground method in try after sFile---------------------------->:" + sFile );   // debug msg
        SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile,true);
        Log.i(TAG, "IN doInBackground method in try after sfos---------------------------->:" + sfos );   // debug msg not getting here
        sfos.write(fileContent.getBytes());

        successful = true;
        System.out.println("Successful" + successful);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        successful = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "IN doInBackground method Exception---------------------------->:" );   // debug msg
        e.printStackTrace();

Logcat:
05-30 13:58:32.180 22183-26454/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool 
I/TomsMessage: IN doInBackground method Exception--------------------------- 
->:
05-30 13:58:32.180 22183-26454/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool 
W/System.err: jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name 
or bad password.
05-30 13:58:32.180 22183-26454/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool    
W/System.err:     at 
jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:546)
05-30 13:58:32.180 22183-26454/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool 
W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
05-30 13:58:32.180 22183-26454/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool 
W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:390)
05-30 13:58:32.180 22183-26454/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool 
W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
```

Comment: I don't think that 'ES File Explore' is using jcifs because it's using smb2 and jcifs using only smb1. Smb1 is not secure almost every OS disable smb1 traffic

Comment: Hello Eliad, Thanks for the response. I noticed you had a mention on a previous post "Android smb2 file transfer via SMBJ". I did more research and it seems like the Windows servers versions are indeed getting away from smb1.  If the jcifs only supports smb1 then would you recommend using smbj-0.6.0.jar library instead? Does it work similarly to jcifs? Thanks again, Tom

Comment: It depends, if you need just to connect without using encryption (I don't think that smbj support or fully support smb3) and you can use open source so yes. But if you need encryption and a commercial license one you can use jNQ by Visuality Systems.